# are there any missing parameters in the async function in the code below?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether

this smart contract will enable the swap of tokens with ether. i used the async function
to write the promises as shown below. i keep getting this error "Error: Invalid number of parameters for "undefined". Got 0 expected 1!"
const Token = artifacts.require('Token')
const EthSwap = artifacts.require('EthSwap')

```
require('chai')
.use(require('chai-as-promised'))
.should()


function tokens(n) {
return web3.utils.toWei(n,'ether');

}

contract('EthSwap', (accounts)=>{
let token, ethSwap

before(async () => {
token = await Token.new()
ethSwap = await EthSwap.new()
await token.transfer(ethSwap.address, tokens('1000000'))

})

describe('Token deployment', async () => {
    it('contract has a name', async () => {
        const name = await token.name()
        assert.equal(name, 'DApp Token')
    })
})

describe('EthSwap deployment', async () => {
    it('contract has a name', async () => {
    const name = await ethSwap.name()
    assert.equal(name, 'EthSwap Instant Exchange')
    })

    it('contract has tokens', async()=>{
        let token = await Token.new()
        const name = await ethSwap.name()
        let balance = await token.balanceOf(ethSwap.address)
        assert.equal(balance.toString(), tokens('1000000'))
    })
})

 })
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.deployed()` instead of `.new()`.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I did that but still got an error. “Returned error : VM Exception while processing transaction: revert